# How to restore a specific version of a record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I am trying to restore a specific version for some given records.

Audit is turned on the entities in question. My program needs to select a certain version from a crm record and reverse all the properties and changes done so the older version of the record gets restored.

This is basically to reverse some changes that happened by accident on a productive system. I am using Xrm to access the server.

Also I tried finding some related functions on the Xrm object or the xrm dataset, but can't find any.

So far I found this way of getting the version history of a given record:

```
            var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(CrmHelper.GetCrmConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Xrm"] + "SG"));

            var changeRequest = new RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest();
            changeRequest.Target = new EntityReference("account", new Guid("{D4E0990C-41C8-E211-B824-005056997F7A}"));

            var changeResponse = (RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse)xrm.Execute(changeRequest);
            var details = changeResponse.AuditDetailCollection;

            for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
            {
                if (typeof (AttributeAuditDetail).Name == details[i].GetType().Name)
                {
                    AttributeAuditDetail detail = details[i] as AttributeAuditDetail;

                    Entity entity = detail.OldValue;
                }
            }
```

However, how can I revert the changes back to the `detail.OldValue`?
Do I have to make a foreach loop over every attribute and set the record's attribute to the ones from the old one?

Comment: I edited, record, not entity

Comment: @GuidoPreite (or any other editors) Please do not change Entity to record!!! In crm what you call a record is defined as an entity and also the class to make an instance of what you call a "record" is called an entity. It's the same as you call a record ListItem in Sharepoint, and not record...

Comment: Let me be clear: inside Dynamics CRM `Entity` is a defined structure composed by fields (like Account and its attributes Name, Address, ...) and `Record` is an instance of an `Entity` (like Company A with Address 110 West Street). `Audit` logs the changes at `Record` level (so changes of the data) not at `Entity` level (like a custom field is added or the Address field has been extended from 100 to 200 chars). Now, if you want to revert accidental changes made at `Record` level, you didn't understand my edit, if you want to revert changes made at `Entity` level, you didn't understand `Audit`

Comment: @GuidoPreite: in the `Microsoft.Xrm` library an `Entity` class in fact _is_ an entity. I think the designers of the SDK have chosen this name with the Domain Driven Design principles in mind. In the DDD vocabulary entities and attributes are key building blocks and their CRM counterparts very well match their purpose. The Entity you are referring to belongs to the data modeling domain. Here it is common to see entities and attributes as the building blocks of the data model. Records and fields define how data is stored in tables and views.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen No, when I say Entity I'm talking about the only thing that inside CRM is an Entity. The fact that inside `Microsoft.Xrm` you need to **instantiate** an `Entity` class (in order to handle records) doesn't means that we can change how the things are called inside CRM. With CRM 4.0 the name was BusinessEntity or DynamicEntity, if you use JS you do `var account = new Object();`. Or tomorrow we need to start to call CRM lookups always as `EntityReference` just because the SDK library use a class with that name in order to handle lookups?

Comment: There is a difference between a class and the instances of the class. You can't say "how to restore a specific version of a class" when your goal is "how to restore a specific version of an **instance** of a class". In Dynamics CRM the class is 'Entity' the instance is a 'Record', the fact that inside `Microsoft.Xrm` the class name is also 'Entity' is irrelevant (and the terminology used by the OP is still wrong)

Comment: @GuidoPreite According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309396.aspx the correct term would be "entity record" or short "record". Seems you are right, I apologise for my claim entity beeing the correct term. EDIT: However this means that CRM SDK does not follow the common accepted naming of classes. Because normally you name the class the same as what you would call the instance. For example if you have a class "Car" and create an instance of it, it gives you an instance of a "Car", and not from the Engine.

Comment: @RononDex you are working with late bound, so the SDK provide the class `Entity`, if you work with early bound you will end up with classes like `Account`, `Contact`, etc. Excuse me if I looked rude in my replies, but with the correct terms more people can understand the question or help your google search.

Comment: @GuidoPreite You did not look rude ;) I apoloigise for reverting your edit. I did a rollback to your edit now. Yes I know this is early bound and XRM provides classes for the different entities. However calling class "Entity" is still not correct in terms of object oriented programming and not-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to reconstruct the original state of your records by traversing the audit history stored in the `AuditDetailCollection` all the way to the point in time where the accidental modifications occurred.

Be aware this can be tricky. E.g. you may run into referential integrity issues. Also custom business logic (plugins, business rules) may block intended updates or have undesired side effects (workflows).

Luckily your corrective update will be recorded in the Audit table, so you will be able to correct that too. :-)

Comment: I was afraid that I have to take this way. I'll try this solution and report back!